# Discord.js embeds looking weird

Tags: discord.js

So, this is how I want something to look. It's from my old bot that I deleted the source code (this was before discord.js v12).[image: How I WANT it to look.1]

However, in my new version, it looks like this:

[image]

Why is it inserting newlines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In old version you use `embed.description` with split `\n`, in new version you use `embed.fields`